# Having trouble with flexbox properties

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have few problems to fix, that are
1- Why logo class properties not working ?
2- Why class title does not move to right, ie justify-content: flex-end not working OR which other way this can be done ?
3- Do I have to write display: flex; in all parent classes or simply container, which has all of them inside is enough ?
4- How it effect if I use display: flex; on all parent classes ?
Many Thanks

---HTML---

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width", initial-scale = 1.0>
    <title>My Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="port.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div id="logo"> Logo </div>
            <div class="title">JAMES O BRAIN
            <div class="sub-title">FRONT-END MONK</div> </div>
        </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="centre-picture">Central Pic</div>
        <div class="left-boxs">
            <div class="blue-box">Blue Box</div>
            <div class="grey-box">Grey Box</div>
            <div class="green-box">Green Box</div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="bottom-boxs">
            <div class="featured-work">Featured Work</div>
            <div class="appify">APPIFY</div>
            <div class="sunflower">SUNFLOWER</div>
            <div class="bokeh">BOKEH</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

---CSS---

```
    .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 50px;
}
.header {
    display: flex;
    border: 5px solid green;
}
.logo {
    /* why these all properties not working at all ? */
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.title { 
    border: 3px solid orange;
  justify-content: flex-end; /* why this property not working, how can i get this to right ?*/
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.sub-title {
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px
}
.container2 {
    display: flex;
    border: 5px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px;

}
.centre-picture {
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.left-boxs {
    border: 3px solid goldenrod;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    order: -1;
}
.green-box {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 
}
.blue-box {
    background-color: blue; 
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px
}
.grey-box {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 
}
.bottom-boxs {
    display: flex;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}
.appify {
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.sunflower {
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.bokeh {
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As Daniel stated, you should make sure that you are not confusing `#id` and `.class` selectors in your markup/CSS. In your stylesheet you should be using `#logo` instead of `.logo`.
2. There are several ways you can align the items in your header. In the example below I attached `justify-content: space-between;` to the `.header` div which will align any direct child elements with an even amount of left over space between them. There are other ways you can do this...this is just one option. You can play around with margins, padding, and other flexbox values to see what works best for you.
3. Giving a container `display: flex` will have effect on all of the children elements inside the container, **but not** the contents inside each of those children.  For example: If you have a container with three `div` elements inside it, and you give the container `display: flex; justify-content: center;` this will center each `div` horizontally, but **not** the text, images, etc, inside each `div`.  In your case, at least in this example, yes, you need to add `display: flex;` to each of the divs inside the header in order to apply flexbox properties to the text inside.

Hope that helps a little.  See the snippet below for one example.  Good luck!

```css
  

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 50px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}

#logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.title { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.sub-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="title">JAMES O BRAIN
      <div class="sub-title">
        FRONT-END MONK
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your HTML you are using an id, `#`, but your CSS is targeting a class `.`. Change your CSS to this instead:

```
#logo {
    /* why these all properties not working at all ? */
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, dont know how I missed that :-)

Comment: There are 3 more questions to be answered ;-)